# Add a Search Button to the function for getting XML data to the HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, rest, button, search

I want to add a search button for my restful web services code,I am getting the data from the database by restful web services java. In this code when I click 'Get Api from db' button, it returns all the values in the database.

**I want to add a search button and search by the name or id and display that details only**.Hope you will help me,Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

   
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get API data from DB</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
    
function loadXMLDoc() {


  var url = "http://localhost:8080/siteuser/webresources/site.users";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Email</th><th>ID</th><th>Password</th><th>User Type</th><th>User Name</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("users");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("password")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("userType")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a search field
2. Pass the value from the search field as a parameter to the AJAX call, e.g. `?search=X`
3. On the server-side, read that parameter and only return the matching records.

Comment: I am not understood it well. Can you give me a example code?